# How can I decode a QR code after preprocessing the given image?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm trying to detect and decode a QR code given in a number of images. The images are unique IDs. I'm using OpenCV to detect the QR code present in that image.

```
def detectQR(filepath):
    img = cv2.imread(filepath)
    qrdetect = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
    decodedText, points, _ = qrdetect.detectAndDecode(img)
    if points is not None:
        print(points)
        print(decodedText)
        #plt.imshow(img)
    else:
        print("QR code not detected")
```

With the above code, openCV is not detecting a QR code present anywhere in the image. So I thought of cropping the image in such a way that I only get the QR code. As the images are sometimes of different sizes, I resize them keeping the scaling of the image same, and then crop accordingly:

```
if img.shape[0] != 337:
    percentage = 33700/img.shape[0]
    width = int(img.shape[1] * percentage/100)
    height = int(img.shape[0] * percentage/100)
    dim = (width, height)
    img = cv2.resize(img, dim)

#print(img.shape)

crop_img = img[50:160, 10:110]
#plt.imshow(crop_img)
```

After the above code I then pass the image to a similar function above. In that function the filepath is not passed, but the cropped image is. The main functionality remains the same.

When I run the code, be it cropping a particular image manually to check, or resizing the images to same dimensions and then cropping those, I do just get the QR code, but however, I do not get the text.

Example:

[image]

I get the points, I get only the QR code which is being detected as well, but it doesn't print the decoded text.

I also tried scanning the same cropped image on my phone, and even the resized and cropped image, but it doesn't give me any output. However, if I scan the original image with the ID, I get the required text.

**I'm not exactly sure at what point I'm going wrong. After checking the documentation, other stackoverflow questions and blogs, I've realised that the code is the same everwhere that I've written, but for all of them, the original image only contains the QR code and no other text so it gets decoded easily. There is no preprocessing done in anything I've checked before.**

***UPDATE:*** I just looked at this [blog](https://machinelearningknowledge.ai/generate-and-decode-qr-code-in-python-with-qrcode-and-pyzbar-library/). They've used **Pyzbar** and **Zbar** to decode a QR image.
I made the following changes:

1. Resize to a generic size and cropped the image so that I get QR code for all images. Empty list returned.
2. Kept the original ID (with image, text etc). Empty list returned.
3. Cropped for each QR code separately (as the images are of different sizes), and then I get the desired result.

So does resizing the image and then cropping it ruin the QR code? If so, how can I still manage to get the QR code from the original image for any ID without resizing the same?

NOTE: The idea behind it is that the user will be uploading his/her/their ID. So the size, lighting and stuff could differ.

Comment: fInd the Square contours and pass it to QR Code Detect. The good practice about qr code is it in square shape

Comment: I've got 3 squares of similar sizes in an image - QR code, Image of the user, and a hallmark kind of sticky thing, not sure what its called.

Comment: OK no problem. When you pass those squares to qrcode detect method then only one will pass which is your qr code.